# Installing Win CE 6.0 licence

Tags: licensing, windows-ce, platform-builder, installation, windows-embedded-compact

We finally managed to develop and test our custom Win CE 6.0 installation. Everything we made on trial version.
Now want to buy the license per device and install it into the target Win CE OS.

Does anybody has the description of the procedure to follow?
Is there any tool into Visual Studio 2005 to do that?

Does the final OS must be compiled with the license into the NK.bin or is it put somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you get your NK.Bin, you can "stamp" it with your Windows CE license using Platform Builder (AKA Visual Studio 2005 with Windows Embedded CE 6.0):

[image]

Look at this page in MSDN for more details:

[Stamping a Run-Time Image (Windows Embedded CE 6.0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478909%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx)

This other post describes how to automate the process using the command line tool stampbin:

[automate the stamping of the CE *.bin File](http://microsoft-personal-operating-systems.hostweb.com/TopicMessages/microsoft.public.windowsce.platbuilder/877519/1/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Simply build the device OS with [ship build (`WINCESHIP`) set to 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms934283.aspx) and put the provided CAL sticker on the device.